# What is this left side panel in Windows 8.1 Xaml App?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I am developing an app where I need a panel like the one shown below. The left panel shown in the second image slides in from the left when the user presses the plus icon next to the English dropdown. [image]
[image]
What is this element and how can I recreate it?
This is a Windows 8.1 C# XAML app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard control to do all of that. Use a Grid and define an animation for the fly-in is the easiest option.

UWP (Win10) has a control to do this, called a SplitView control. More information on that an how to use it can [be found on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn997787.aspx).

Martin

Answer (score 1):

you should use Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.SettingsFlyout control, here is a sample that shows you how to configure the settingflyout https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-settings-sample-1f762f49
thats what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

For creating this menu for windows 8.1 need create own control, then create style for him and etc. 
Please see this post:

[How to create a hamburger menu control for Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/madenwal/archive/2015/03/25/how-to-create-a-hamburger-menu-control-for-windows-8-1-and-windows-phone.aspx)

But if you create WUP app it is very simple ;)

[Windows 10 SplitView – Build Your First Hamburger Menu](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/quick_thoughts/archive/2015/06/01/windows-10-build-your-first-hamburger-menu.aspx)

p.s. if you need create hamburger menu for windows phone 8.1 existing more nu-get packages for him, like this: SlideView : [Facebook-like panel for Windows Phone](https://slideview.codeplex.com/)

Good luck.